# Read a zip file line by line, or decompress first?

Tags: java, zip

I have a zipped csv file that is going to be processed on a regular basis 3-4x a day. Size may be from 500-1000mb.

I want to read the contained csv lines line by line. Is it therefore better to first unzip the file and read it then, or could I as well use the java Zip stream to read the file?

Is there any advantage (performance?) of one approach over the other?

Comment: .zip is 1000mb, or the csv data is 1000mb? a zipped csv is probably going to be MUCH larger than the 1000mb zip that contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the slowest activities for a computer is hard drive access (at least until SSDs are more common).  So unzipping it and then reading the unzipped file will be significantly slower.

You will get much better performance reading lines directly from a ZipInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion unzipping is faster and possibly simpler. If performance is important, test both methods. If the disk space is limited which is not the case nowadays, then you have no choice but to read within the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Zipping and Unzipping will both be time expensive.

If can access your .csv file without unzipping (I don't know if your .csv file is difficult to read in its compressed state), then you can open the .CSV file as a RandomAccessFile to only work with particular lines instead of the entire file.

This may or may not be applicable, but at the very least, it would improve performance greatly since you would only read/write data from where you need to.